# Logistic Equation and population growth model

Tags: calculus

Hey had a confusion in understanding whats the difference between these two equation. First one is 100 percent for sure logistic equation but the second one seems to be one but i struggle to understand all the constant used in the equation. 
So are these equation same and whats the difference? 
first: 
 $$N(t)= \frac{KN}/{N}+(K-N)e^{-rt} $$
Second: 
$$
\frac{d N(t)}{dt} = \frac{aN(t)(a − bN(t))}{a} 
$$

--

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In what you have written you can cancel the $N$ in the first term on the right in the first equation. In the second equation you can cancel the $a$. Are you sure that's what you want? Please [edit] the question to clarify. Don't respond in a comment.

Comment: hello the first equation is the logistic equation and second is the one which i found from this link http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2011/ams-53-56-2011/waliAMS53-56-2011.pdf but couldnot understand the way author defines logistic equation.

Comment: The second equation is a differential equation. These are two different ways to approximate $N(t)$, in the article, the formula you are looking for is #7

Answer (score 0):

You have a fraction with just "/" in the denominator.  I might guess that you intended the "N" immediately after that to be in the denominator but that would immediately cancel the "N" in the numerator.  You also have "a" in both numerator and denominator of the second equation which should be canceled.  Yes, that occurs as equation "4" but the "a"s have been canceled in equation "5". It would have been better too have posted equation "5" rather than equation "4"!

As shown in the paper, you can rewrite $\frac{dN}{dt}= N(a- bN)dt$ as $\frac{dN}{N(a- bN)}= dt$ and integrate both sides.  Use "partial fractions" to integrate the left side- $\frac{dN}{N(a- bN)}$ can be written as $\frac{C dN}{N}+ \frac{D dN}{a- bN}$ for some numbers C and D.

To find C and D write $\frac{1}{N(a- bN)}= \frac{C}{N}+ \frac{dN}{a- bN}$ and multiply both sides by $N(a- bN)$ to get $1= C(a- bN)+ DN$ which must be true for all N.  To find C and D choose two different values for N to get two equations to solve for C and D.  We can get particularly easy equations by taking N= 0 and N= a/b.  If N=  0 we have $1= C(a- 0b)+ D(0)= C$.  If N= a/b we have $1= C(0)+ D(a/b)$ so $D= b/a$.

So we have $\frac{dN}{N}+ \frac{b}{a}\frac{dN}{a- bN}= dt$ all of which are easy to integrate.

Comment: the website which i tried to get some help in logistic model is: m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2011/ams-53-56-2011/waliAMS53-56-2011.pdf but, it defines the logistic  equation in different form as mentioned above (the second one) which made me wonder is author right about it or am i too stupid to understand it?